# JSP/HTML trouble, accessing an object from an ArrayList of Objects using a variable as the index

Tags: java, html, jsp, object, arraylist

I´m having some trouble with what seems to be a simple problem,

I have a obtained a result from another method which has in it a list of objects, each of those with their own properties,
When I access the objects properties as below and print them it works fine.

The problem originates when I introduce a variable to determine which object I´m refering to.
I named this variable index which is a String, and I also tried transforming it to an int.

```
<c:out value="${result.listOfObjects[0].propertyA}"/>           <%--WORKS--%>
<%
String index="0";                                               <%-- Always a number--%>

int ind = Integer.parseInt(index);
%>


<c:out value="${result.listOfObjects[index].propertyA}"/>       <%--DOESN´T WORK--%>    
<c:out value="${result.listOfObjects[ind].propertyA}"/>         <%--DOESN´T WORK--%>
```

Neither one is working correctly, I´m guessing its a matter of syntax but I can´t seem to get it right..
Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)
Thank you in advance for your time!!

PS: The program is a .jsp.

Comment: look at using `<c:set`  In reality, where will index come from?

Answer (score 0):

index and ind are not recognized within the  JSTL tag because you declared them using plain java.

In order to achieve your expected output, try using the  JSTL tag mentioned by @Scary Wombat.

```
<c:set var="index" value="${0}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention.  is `value="${0}"` correct?

Comment: why not `value="0"` - maybe I am missing your intention.